# Novos elementos não funcionam uma função - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde!
Não tenho muita experiencia com jquery, por isso estou tendo problemas. Estou criando um novo elemento quando clicko em um botão.

```
$('#tbody_6').append('<tr id="'+token+'"><td><input required id="time_ini_6['+token+']" class="form-control" type="time" name="time_ini_6['+token+']"><input required class="form-control" type="time" id="time_max_6['+token+']" name="time_max_6['+token+']"><input id="price_6['+token+']" name = "price_6['+token+']"type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Preço" value="" autofocus><button class="btn btn-md btn-alt btn-danger" id="minus_'+token+'" onclick="removePeriod(this)" type="button"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td></tr>');
```

Criando algo mais ou menos assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após isso queria chamar uma função pra retornar o id desse meu botão de remoção.

```
        function removePeriod(elem){
            var id = $(elem).attr("id");
            console.log(id);    
    }
```

Mas isso não está acontecendo, eu recebo sempre um erro[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Essa função `removePeriod` está definida no escopo global? Me parece que o seu elemento não está conseguindo enxergar a função.

Comment: Estava definida dentro de $(document).ready(function ().... Dessa forma, ele não conseguia encontrar. Deixei apenas dentro das tags script e tirei de dentro de document.ready e funcionou pra mim. Obrigado